# xetex + unicode-math + tilde on bold characters

Tags: xetex, accents, unicode-math, boldmath

I would like produce bold characters with accents such as ~.

Using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
z = x + y \\
\tilde{z} = \tilde{x} + \tilde{y} \\
\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} \\ 
\mathbf{\tilde{z}} = \mathbf{\tilde{x}} + \mathbf{\tilde{y}}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
γ = α + β \\
\tilde{γ} = \tilde{α} + \tilde{β} \\
\mathbf{γ} = \mathbf{α} + \mathbf{β} \\ 
\mathbf{\tilde{γ}} = \mathbf{\tilde{α}} + \mathbf{\tilde{β}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Produces something like this where the tilde is missing on the bold characters:

[image: With unicode-math]

However commenting out unicode-math produces the bold characters with tilde, but does not print the greek characters.:

[image: Without unicode math]

I am using MikTex 2.9 and Xetex.
Ignore the missing bold greek characters which I suspect is xits-mathbold missing on my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `\mathbf` doesn't play nice with `unicode-math`. As you might notice, apart with the tilde gone, the boldface font became from the *Computer Modern* family instead of *XITS Math*. So, don't use `\mathbf` with `unicode-math`. Use either `\symbfup` or `\symbfit`, which suits you better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\tilde{z} = \tilde{x} + \tilde{y} \\
\symbfit{\tilde{z}} = \symbfit{\tilde{x}} + \symbfit{\tilde{y}}\\
\symbfup{\tilde{z}} = \symbfup{\tilde{x}} + \symbfup{\tilde{y}}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\tilde{γ} = \tilde{α} + \tilde{β} \\
\symbfit{\tilde{γ}} = \symbfit{\tilde{α}} + \symbfit{\tilde{β}}\\
\symbfup{\tilde{γ}} = \symbfup{\tilde{α}} + \symbfup{\tilde{β}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Additionally it also fixed the missing bold greek characters.

Comment: On the other hand, the tilde accent itself is no longer boldface. And I don't know a good way to make it bold for a single character. You can play with `XITS Math Bold` font for truly bold math.

Comment: For my purpose it is not important if the tilde is bold or not.